# Is there way to apply htmlspecialchars() or html_escape() whole PHP / Codeigniter base website?

Tags: php, codeigniter, htmlspecialchars

I have build a Codeigniter based system.

When edit screens I take values from database and display on input fields.

Example :

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" name="tes_title" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($tes_info['tes_title']); ?>">
```

So I had to use `htmlspecialchars` because some values contains double quotes and single quotes. But adding them manually to all input takes lot of time.

Is there any way to apply `htmlspecialchars()` or `html_escape()` whole site wise?

I mean even I use `<input type="text" class="form-control" required="" name="tes_title" value="<?php echo $tes_info['tes_title']; ?>">` it should be worked as `<input type="text" class="form-control" required="" name="tes_title" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($tes_info['tes_title']); ?>">`

Comment: You can do this in the function you return in `$tes_info`. For example: `function getResults(){ (your query) $result = [(all your items in an array)]; foreach{ $result htmlspecialchars($value)} return $result}` . This code wont work as its written, but perhaps you get the idea.

Comment: write a function for apply your logic and put it on a helper. Then you can use it anywhere you want

Comment: Smarty can do that! There is a library to integrate it into ci on github just be ready to convert all your views

Answer (score 0):

Write a convenience function.

```
<?php

function e($str) {
    //return escaped string.
}
```

And use for output where needed:

```
<?= e($foo) ?>
```

But I'd confine it to your input outputs.  Escape where needed and escape appropriately.

Codeigniter looks to have an `html_escape` helper function baked in, which is a wrapper around htmlspecialchars.  It will also take an array as input.

You could preprocess the data before you pass to the view (in the controller).  But it could become confusing and unwieldy - you might not want to escape everything that you pass through to the view.

```
$data = array(
        'title' => 'My Title',
        'heading' => 'My Heading',
        'message' => 'My Message'
);

$escaped = html_escape($data);

$this->load->view('blogview', $escaped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define hook for every submission.

Edit your application/config/hooks.php file

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(                                 'class'    => 'SpecialChar', 
'function' => 'remove_specials',
'filename' => 'removespecial.php', 
'filepath' => 'hooks'  
);
```

In your function, you have to check if form submitted

ex :

```
if ($this->input->post()) {    
     foreach($this->input->post() as $post)
     $newValue = htmlspecialchars($post);
}
```

Comment: Escaping for html output is quite different to filtering/escaping input.